# most expensive item's >> NAME << function

Tags: javascript

I have been learning Javascript for couple of weeks now, and this is where I got stuck for last two days.
I am pretty sure it is the most obvious line of code but I can't match my most expensive item's number with it's name.

This is what I have:

```js
function mostExpensiveItemName(sampleCart) {
  let expensive = 0;
  var name;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < sampleCart.length; i++) {
  
    if(sampleCart[i].price > 0) {
    
      expensive += sampleCart[i].price;
      name += sampleCart[i].itemName;
    }
  }
    return name;
}
```

these are the data:

```js
const sampleCart = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide much more information. What is the shape of the object in the list?
What are you trying to do? Why?

Comment: sorry for that just added the data

Comment: Much better! Now, I'm not sure if there are any SO answers for simple stuff like this though.

Comment: Seems you are trying to find the most expensive item's name. Your logic is incorrect. Here is the starting point. `if(sampleCart[i].price > expensive ) {    
      expensive = sampleCart[i].price;
      name= sampleCart[i].itemName;
    }`

Comment: it prints the price when run, but can't match it with itemName or it prints everything that it looped

Comment: ooohwiii thank you @Satpal it worked. It was bugging me for few days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const sampleCart = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
];

function mostExpensiveItemName(sampleCart) {
  let expensive = 0;
  var name;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < sampleCart.length; i++) {
  
    if(sampleCart[i].price > expensive) {
    
      expensive = sampleCart[i].price;
      name = sampleCart[i].itemName;
    }
  }
    return name;
}

console.log(mostExpensiveItemName(sampleCart));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ES6](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_versions.asp) features and [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the cart items by price and then get the most expensive, for example:

```js
function mostExpensiveItemName(sampleCart) {
  const sortBypriceCart = sampleCart.sort((itemA, itemB) =>
      // sort descending by price 
      itemB?.price - itemA?.price);
  const expensiveItem = sortBypriceCart[0];

  return expensiveItem.itemName
}
```

with you code will be:

```js
function mostExpensiveItemName(sampleCart) {
  let expensive = 0;
  let name;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < sampleCart.length; i++) {
    // compares if the next value is higher and replaces it
    if(sampleCart[i].price > expensive) {
      expensive = sampleCart[i].price; // += is to sum/add values to the same variables, does not apply here
      name = sampleCart[i].itemName; // assign the possible final name
    }
  }
  return name;
}
```

`for` always will be faster than for example `forEach`, but `sort` is a good alternative and it's faster than `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const sampleCart = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.0
  }
];

function mostExpensiveItemName(sampleCart) {
  // lets find the biggest number
  const biggestPrice = Math.max(...sampleCart.map((item) => item.price));

  return sampleCart.find((item) => item.price === biggestPrice).itemName;
}

console.log(mostExpensiveItemName(sampleCart));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfectly clear, but it seems like you are looking for the most expensive item's name.

The code seems to contain quite a few logical errors.

```
function mostExpensiveItemName(sampleCart) {
    let expensive = 0;
    var name;

    for (let i = 0; i < sampleCart.length; i++) {
        if (sampleCart[i].price > 0) {
            expensive += sampleCart[i].price;
            name += sampleCart[i].itemName;
        }
    }

    return name;
}
```

You assign the name to a variable when instead, you should just return the item's name.

```
function mostExpensiveItemName(sampleCart) {
    let mostExpensive = sampleCart[0];

    for (let i = 1; i < sampleCart.length; ++i) {
        if (sampleCart[i].price > mostExpensive.price) {
            expensive = sampleCart[i];
        }
    }

    return mostExpensive.itemName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do it is to iterate over the array - compare the price to the existing max price and set an index if its greater - the index is then used to rerun the itemName from the array.

```js
const sampleCart = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
];

function mostExpensiveItemName(arr) {
  var mostExpensive = 0;
  var mostExpensiveIndex = 0;

 arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
  if(item.price > mostExpensive) {
   mostExpensive = item.price;
   mostExpensiveIndex = index;
  }
 })
    return sampleCart[mostExpensiveIndex].itemName;
}

console.log(mostExpensiveItemName(sampleCart)); // gives Creation 3005
```

Comment: I haven't learned about arr.forEach(function(item, index) yet. Thanks!